# Pass a php string to a javascript variable

Tags: plugins, php, jquery, javascript, array

I need to pass a php string that is stored in `$attr['footer_caption']` inside a shortcode function to a js file where the highcharts are initialized.

```
$fields = array(

        array(
            'label' => esc_html( 'Footer label' ),
            'description' => esc_html( 'Choose the footer label' ),
            'attr' => 'footer_caption',
            'type' => 'text',
        ),


public static function shortcode_ui_chart( $attr, $content, $shortcode_tag ) {

    $attr = shortcode_atts( array(
        'chart' => null,
        'footer_caption' => null,
    ), $attr, $shortcode_tag );
```

I've been reading about localize script but couldnt get it to work. Is there a simple way to perfom this? I want the string from that php array in this variable:

```
    Highcharts.setOptions({
  chart: {
          type: 'column',
          events: {
              load: function () {
                var teste 'WANT TO PASS $attr['footer_caption'] HERE'
                var label = this.renderer.label(teste)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you post how you tried to use localize_script? Because i use the function often for passing PHP vars to JavaScript and it always worked.

Another way would be to echo the variable in `shortcode_ui_chart` so you later can use it in your script:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">var footer_caption = "' . $attr['footer_caption'] . '"</script>';
```

With this code you can use the variable `footer_caption` in your javascript.

EDIT:
See comments for code explanation

```
var chart1 = Highcharts.chart({
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: function () {
                var caption 'footer_caption'
                var label = this.renderer.label(caption)
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, but i've got one more problem. The js file always outputs the last value of 'footer_caption' in the footer of all charts

Comment: I don't know Highcharts, but according to their [documentation about setting options](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/how-to-set-options) you can set options [global](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/how-to-set-options#2) (for all charts) or [local](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/how-to-set-options#1) (for one specific chart). You are setting the options global, so it affects all charts. You have to set the footer local, if it should only be shown on one chart.

Comment: See answer for js-code with local options

Answer (score 1):

You can use the wp_localize_script to pass a variable to your javascript.

Here is an example:

```
wp_register_script('your_script_name', 'path/to/script.js');
$variables = array (
    'footer_caption' => $attr['footer_caption'],
);
wp_localize_script('your_script_name', 'js_object_name', $variables );
wp_enqueue_script('your_script_name');
```

Then you can acces to this variable by:

```
js_object_name.footer_caption
```